# Overlapping progressbar in Vaadin 8

Tags: java, progress-bar, vaadin, vaadin8

I am wondering if I can achieve something like this in Vaadin 8:

[image: overlapping progressbar]

The orange bar represents one progress and the green represents another one, which is subset of the orange. Basically, the green bar can be smaller or equal to the orange.

Right now, I have only

[image: simple progressbar]

Following is the code:

```
        AbstractLayout progressBarInformationLayout = 

        VaadinLayoutUtility.getInstance().generateHLayout();
        progressBarInformationLayout.setStyleName("dashboard_progress_bar_info_layout");
        layout.addComponent(progressBarInformationLayout);

        float progressBarValue = actualIncludeTotal / (float) predictedInclude;
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(progressBarValue);
        progressBar.setId("dashboard_progress_bar");
        progressBar.setWidth("230px");
        progressBar.setStyleName("progress_bar");
        progressBarInformationLayout.addComponent(progressBar);

        Label progressLabel = new Label(df2.format(progressBarValue * 100) + "%");
        progressLabel.setStyleName("progress_label");
        progressBarInformationLayout.addComponent(progressLabel);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but I'd assume it's semi-easily doable by extending/overriding ProgressBar and its related classes to have two or more progress indicators.

See the handling of `indicator` variable in [VProgressBar](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/client/src/main/java/com/vaadin/client/ui/VProgressBar.java), calling of `getWidget().setState(getState().state);` in [ProgressBarConnector](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/client/src/main/java/com/vaadin/client/ui/progressbar/ProgressBarConnector.java), variable `state` in [ProgressBarState](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/shared/src/main/java/com/vaadin/shared/ui/progressindicator/ProgressBarState.java), and the `getValue` and `setValue` handling in [ProgressBar](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/ProgressBar.java) -- you are going to need to duplicate all of those. You'll also need styling for the extra indicators (see [Valo styles for ProgressBar](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/themes/src/main/themes/VAADIN/themes/valo/components/_progressbar.scss)).

Given that three of the above are client-side classes, take a look at the [Client-Side Development documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/clientside/clientside-overview) if you aren't familiar with it from before, and remember to recompile your widgetset after every change.

If you ever want a version where the second bar isn't a subset of the first one but a completely different progress, and don't know upfront which task is slowest, I suppose you'll also need extra logic for determining which bar is underneath (otherwise the faster one might hide the slower one), and possibly for swapping the colors of the bars if their relative speed changes. Or you could tweak the design so that both bars are always visible.